# How can I get the Android Ubuntu One Music app to eagerly cache everything locally?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I've set the "Cache size" to 10GB (which is enough to hold all my music) and "Songs to preload" to "Unlimited" but the phone only seems to cache files locally when I play them or they appear in the queue.  What I'd love is to button that says "fill up the cache" that downloads everything that fits (which in my case would be everything).  Anyone know to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Long press an artist and select **Save all**. You can also do that on a per-album basis. Sadly, there's no 'fill up cache' / 'download as much as you can' option, so you would have to do that for each artist. You either need to indicate you want to download music, or just listen to it, while it gets opportunistically cached. I hope this helps.